# My Edit Button and Delete Button are conficting

Tags: vb.net, listview, inventory-management

I am trying to edit my records in the list view using VB.net after I code my select list view and edit button it works but after I code my delete button it starts to do error

Here's my Edit button

```
    txtID.Text = CustomerList.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text
    txtFN.Text = CustomerList.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text
    txtLN.Text = CustomerList.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(2).Text
    txtAdr.Text = CustomerList.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(3).Text
    cbOrder.Text = CustomerList.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(4).Text
    cbPaymen.Text = CustomerList.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(5).Text
    DatePicker.Text = CustomerList.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(6).Text

End Sub
```

Here's my List view Select code

```
    Dim s = n1 + n2 + n4 + n8
    br = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()

    CustomerList.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text = txtFN.Text
    CustomerList.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(2).Text = txtLN.Text
    CustomerList.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(3).Text = txtAdr.Text
    CustomerList.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(4).Text = cbOrder.Text
    CustomerList.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(5).Text = cbPaymen.Text
    CustomerList.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(6).Text = DatePicker.Text
    CustomerList.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(7).Text = i
    CustomerList.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(8).Text = br
    CustomerList.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(9).Text = s

End Sub
```

Here's my Delete Button Code

```
  CustomerList.Items.Remove(CustomerList.SelectedItems(0))
```

and I get an error:

> ArgumentOutofRangeException was unhandled

when I remove my listview select code both buttons work fine tho

please help

Comment: A `ListView` is not a grid control so don't try to use it as one. Get rid of it, put your datta into a `DataTable`, bind that to a `BindingSource` and then bind that to a `DataGridView`. You can bind the same `BindingSource` to your individual controls as well and then there's no code required at all to move data back and forth; it all happens automatically. Deleting is a simple task of calling `RemoveCurrent` on the `BindingSource`.

Comment: is data table different from datagridview? I tried using it before but I just don't get how it works

Comment: Is a String different to a TextBox? Yes they are different. There's lots of examples around of binding a DataTable to a DataGridView. You should read up, do what you can and then ask a question specifically about that.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a selected ListView item get the index of the selected item Then use that index to identify the item to remove.

```
Private Sub RemoveListViewItem()
    Dim myIndex As Integer = CustomerList.SelectedIndices(0)
    CustomerList.Items(myIndex).Remove()
End Sub
```